# postgresql operation within a table and find result from two different result from operating in same table

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm using postgresql here 
Here's a field in my table "num": 
**adsh**: some numeric with dash eg.(1234-23456-456789)
**tag**: character eg.(ReturnOnAsset)
**version**: can be one of two format 1. exactly same as adsh 2. us-gaap/yyyy eg. (us-gaap/2009)
there are some other column but not important
primary key is the 3 column above and some other column combine.
for each adsh, there's several version value us-gaap/dei/invest + yyyy or 
Also keep in mind that there's 10^8 tuples in this table

step one: `select tag, version from num where version=adsh as result a`
step two: `select adsh, version from num where version!=adsh as result b`
step three: `select tag, b.version from a, b where a.version=b.adsh`

I wonder if I can save the first two steps' result temporarily for in order to do the third step. Can I do that. What's the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution using with clause:

```
with a as (select tag, version from num where version=adsh), b as (select adsh, version from num where version!=adsh) select tag, b.version from a, b where a.version=b.adsh;
```